# Backend Module with AJAX in Typo3 6.2.6?

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-6.2.x

I am working on an extension which contains both FE extension and BE Module. See below for my BE module

```
class Tx_XXXXXXX_Controller_PitslayersliderController extends Tx_Extbase_MVC_Controller_ActionController {

public function listAction(){

}
public function getdataAction($params = array(), \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Http\AjaxRequestHandler &$ajaxObj = NULL) {
 //This is an AJAX Call Action and I am rendering all my contents through
 //$this->view->assign();
 //$this->view->render();
 //Everything was working fine till 6.1 . But from 6.2 onwards this is not working.

}

}
```

ext_tables.php

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::registerAjaxHandler (
    'xxxxxxxxxController::getdata',
    'Tx_xxxxxxxxxx_Controller_xxxxxxxController->getdataAction'
);
```

Error from php_error_log
    `PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function assign() on a non-object in`

Can any one help me with this issue ??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25772722/how-to-render-a-fuid-view-template-without-extbase-i-e-an-email-template-by-ei

could give you a push in the right direction

Comment: OK Thanks !! I will try this and will update my feedbacks here !!