# TYPO3 change template inside action method

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x

In my ext I have `singleAction` method. I want to change template inside this method, because I have 2 templates for single action. Is it possible? If it impossible, how can I solve this problem? Maybe generate another action?

Answer (score 3):

It's not that simple to set a template. the `setTemplate` and `getTemplate` don't exist in the View.
You could revert to a standaloneview implemtation, which supports the use of `setTemplatePathAndFilename`

(example copied from [Ludwig](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25773131/3997594))

```php
/**
 * Renders the fluid email template
 * @param string $template
 * @param array $assign
 * @return string
 */
public function renderFluidTemplate($template, Array $assign = array()) {
    $templatePath = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::getFileAbsFileName('EXT:myextension/Resources/Private/Templates/' . $template);

    $view = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance('TYPO3\\CMS\\Fluid\\View\\StandaloneView');
    $view->setTemplatePathAndFilename($templatePath);
    $view->assignMultiple($assign);

    return $view->render();
}

echo renderFluidTemplate('mail.html', array('test' => 'This is a test!'));
```

You could also switch to a different template with typoscript.

```
plugin.tx_yourpluginname.view.templateRootPaths = EXT:extension_name/Resources/Private/CustomPath/Templates/
```

And this can be put into any typoscript condition you want.

Comment: Ha, turns out you're right. I've used my code in context of StandaloneView.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to handle this is simply to have a switch in the template of the action, loading a different partial. This way the whole flow of logic stays intact and it's immediately understandable for everyone who will have to edit your code later on.